# Can I use a helper method to throw an execption

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a HashMap which rejects null keys. When my map receives a null key, it will throw an IllegalArgumentException.

I found it dull to add lines of detection code in every method, so I create a helper method to relieve myself:

```java
private void keyDetect(K key) {
    if (null == key) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should not be null!");
    }
}
```

And now I'm wondering that will this cause any problem? I mean, does invoking this method have the same effect as adding a piece of code like this directly to the method? I'm new to Java and I feel weird about this.

Comment: You should 100% use a private helper function to do this. You seem to already have a great instinct for when to split a chunk of code into a separate function, and you should trust that instinct. You'll still need to add calls to your helper in every `Map` method, but that's far more maintainable than writing the same check manually in each function.

Comment: You are surely thinking: "is the key null" and not "is null the key". Therefore, write `if (key == null)`.  Backwards expressions a pox of poor C style are.

Comment: This is fairly subjective, imo. There are times such a method is useful, and times it adds indirection for little gain. Often it's largely a matter of taste as to where it falls. You may also want to consider an existing method, like [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)). There are overloads that let you specify a string, though imo you rarely actually need that: the stack trace will very quickly point you at what went wrong.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thanks! So this way is useful here. It has been bothering me for a while, and now it's clear.

Comment: Note there are libraries out there that provide "preconditions" utility classes, similar to 
(but more extensive than) the `Objects` class mentioned by yshavit. For instance, there's [Guava's `Preconditions`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) and [Apache Common Lang's `Validate`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... does invoke this method have the same effect as adding a piece of code like this directly to the method? ..."*

More or less.  The *scope* will be different, of course, and it's an extra call to the *stack*.
This topic is typically covered in most *Java* introductory tutorials.

> *"... I'm try to implement a HashMap which rejects null key. When my map receive a null key, it will throw an IllegalArgumentException. ..."*

You can *encapsulate* the *HashMap* class, and *override* the *put* method to evaluate a *null* key *argument*.

Here is an example.

```java
class HashMapNonNull<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should not be null!");
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

And, here is an example usage.

```java
HashMapNonNull<String, Integer> map = new HashMapNonNull<>();
map.put(null, 1);
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key should not be null!
    at Example$HashMapNonNull.put(Example.java:15)
    at Example.main(Example.java:8)
```

Additionally, you may want to *override* the *putAll* and *putIfAbscent* methods.

```java
@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    for (K k : m.keySet())
        if (k == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should not be null!");
    super.putAll(m);
}
```

```java
@Override
public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should not be null!");
    return super.putIfAbsent(key, value);
}
```